# Advertise additional information with Substrates Libp2p?

Tags: substrate, libp2p

Substrate uses libp2p to do peer discovery and transport.

Is there functionality to advertise additional information from peers using this layer? Or alternatively, use substrate to advertise information without needing to sink that information to the chain?

For instance, the location of additional RPC endpoints attached to the light clients.

Answer (score 1):

Re: shawntabrizi

one big issue about light clients and not storing that data to chain is that light client inherently depend on merkle proofs and this merkle trie is where all the overhead of runtime storage comes from practically speaking, so if you want some light-client verifiable content using only the runtime state, then you are basically stuck with this but you could store only a hash of some file
and then use any other p2p protocol to share that file
and let the light client verify based on the hash
but this would be a third party tool or possibly an offchain worker on top of a substrate client|

You should be able to make modifications to networking to enable different kinds of gossiping for your needs. AFAIK, Polkadot does this: https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/tree/master/network

a few parties use IPFS, including ourselves at parity, that have investigated IPFS integration. I am not to certain on the latest progress from 3rd party teams, but we had a very old branch that adds an IPFS node along side the Substrate node. Because Substrate and IPFS use LibP2P, this was relatively painless from what I understand.